# Capture words that do not have hyphen in it - Python

Tags: python, regex

For example we have this text:

#### Hello but I don't want1 this non-object word in it.

Using regular expression, how can extract words that must start with a letter and that only have letters or numbers in it? For example in this example I only want:

#### Hello but I want1 this word in it

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Why is "it" included?  It has a "."

Comment: "Want1" starts with a letter and is only letters and numbers, but you don't include it.  Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds in your regex:

```
>>> str = "Hello but I don't want1 this non-object word in it."
>>> print re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))\w+(?=[.\s]|$)', str)
['Hello', 'but', 'I', 'want1', 'this', 'word', 'in', 'it']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLTP2j/5)

Comment: Hi: Thanks! That really helps a lot! I just edited my post because I actually want that 'want1' in my outcome instead of 'want'. How to solve this?

Comment: You will get `want1` in output using same regex I suggested as `want1` is also be matched using `\w+` (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

> extract words that must start with a **letter** and that only have **letters** **or**
>   **numbers** in it

The alternative solution using `re.sub` function(from `re` module):

```
s = "Hello but I don't want this non-object word in it."
s = re.sub(r'\s?\b[a-zA-Z]+?[^\w ][\w]+?\b', '', s)

print(s)
```

The output:

```
Hello but I want this word in it.
```